# Class Solution - NameError: name 'Solution' is not defined

Tags: python, oop

I tried all possible things to resolve this on compilation but still get this message. Is there anything wrong with class and function definition ?

```py
class Solution:

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):

        s = 'tracecars'

    print(str(Solution().longestPalindrome(s)))
```

PyCharm 2019.1.3 with Python 3.8

> File "C:/Nityam/PythonProjects/DailyProblems/Palindrome.py", line 1,
>   in 
>       class Solution:
>
> File "C:/Nityam/PythonProjects/DailyProblems/Palindrome.py", line 7,
>   in Solution
>       print(str(Solution().longestPalindrome(s))) NameError: name 'Solution' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please correct the indentation of needed.

Comment: Your function also doesn't return anything, so your print will just output `None`

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ please do not edit indentation of code when the indentation is a likely cause of the issue---it should be asked of OP to correct their code instead of assuming.

Comment: print is in wrong scope or as @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ said correct your indentation

Comment: @alkasm I did not change indentation of code , I just tabed class part for correct code format.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ - When the likely issue is indentation, editing the given indentation at all is likely to result in answers being the incorrect expected output, its generally better imo to just vote to close as "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information." and move on

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ In this case it's pretty clear that you're right, but you should not make formatting edits by indentation unless it's not relevant to the issue. Otherwise it is very easy to accidentally introduce more problems (this is extremely common in the review queue); it's best to link to [the code formatting canonical on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and ask OP to edit. To the OP, can you please review that link and edit your post to be formatted correctly, so that it is indented the same as your editor?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we can't reproduce your error.

Second one - your class method doesn't return anything.

Third - you don't create class object (it's OK - you can create it inline as you did, but why then do you need a class?)

Maybe you want something like this:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        s = 'tracecars'
        # some code here
        return s



solution_obj = Solution()
print(str(solution_obj.longestPalindrome('somestring')))
```

also read about `__init__` method for class - maybe you want s be a inner class variable (field)?

Comment: Thank you very much, the above solution worked and gave me below output "tracecars", I'm a beginner in Python. Can you explain me what exactly was wrong with my program. If Solution is mentioned as class on first line then why did you create a Soultion() method and assigned it to the variable solution_obj ?  :  C:\Users\nitya\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Nityam/PythonProjects/DailyProblems/Palindrome.py
tracecars

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @user2306388 you problem was with indentation. Because you add 4 spaces before print python think that print is still in class definition. But really it is not, it is already usage of the class.